# Remove empty field when extracting using Xpath / Scrapy

Tags: python, html, xpath, scrapy

I use Scrapy/Xpath to extract data and generate the field (**typeFacture**)

But it generates the field and another empty field with (**''**).

I want to extract that text and delete the empty field with (**''**) to insert it into a database.

> HTML code:

```
<td class="tNorm tSmall-xs">
    <b>FACTURE</b>
    <br>
''
    Commission
   ''
</td>
```

> Python code:

```
 item['typeFacture']  = [item.strip() for item in sel.xpath('//tbody/tr/td[5]/text()').extract()]
```

> result:

```
'typeFacture': ['',
             '',
             'Commission',
             '',
             '',
             'Commission',
             '',
             '',
             'Commission',
             '',
             '',
             'Commission',
             '',
             '',
             'Abonnement']}
```

Comment: Don't put images, put the code.

Comment: Please paste your html code, desired and actual result as text instead of links to images.

Comment: thank you for your advice, I changed, do you have an idea about this problem?

Comment: something like this maybe `item['typeFacture']  = [item.strip() for item in sel.xpath('//tbody/tr/td[5]/text()').extract() if item]`

Comment: Why is commision repeating ? Your html doesn't have it multiple times?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, but not with XPATH.
I use it in a simple python code, before inserting it in the database

```
item['typeFacture'] = list(filter(None, item['typeFacture']))
```